# Calling multiple ACF field - how do I write my code prettier?

Tags: php

Im using a bunch of ACF fields for my WooCommerce email templates and for this example Im calling these in my email_header template. Im using this with WPML, and need to call each language settings. The code works, but seems like it should be a way to write this better.

This is used to set and fetch the correct language based on meta data on orders. Works well. For this I created an array to shorten it down for each if/else statement. NL is the default language.

```
$language = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'wpml_language', true );
if ($language == 'en') {
```

For the front, this is used to fetch the right language:

```
} elseif (ICL_LANGUAGE_CODE=='en') {
```

For this statement to get the correct language, I need to ad a language prefix to each ACF variable, so it doesn't work to use the variable from the array, it defaults to NL then:

```
$sitelogo = get_field('en_logo', 'options');
```

How can I shorten this down? full code:

```
 $header_variabls_one = $sitelogo = get_field('logo', 'options'); 
     $header_variabls_two = $emailLogoLink = get_field('email_logo_link', 'options');
     $header_variabls_three = $sitelogo = get_field('logo', 'options'); 
     $header_variabls_four = $header_link_one = get_field('header_links_link_one', 'options');
     $header_variabls_five = $header_link_one_url = get_field('header_links_link_one_url', 'options');
     $header_variabls_six =  $header_link_two = get_field('header_links_link_two', 'options');
     $header_variabls_seven = $header_link_two_url = get_field('header_links_link_two_url', 'options');
     $header_variabls_eight = $header_link_three = get_field('header_links_link_three', 'options');
     $header_variabls_nine = $header_link_three_url = get_field('header_links_link_three_url', 'options');
     $header_variabls_ten = $header_link_four = get_field('header_links_link_four', 'options');
     $header_variabls_eleven = $header_link_four_url = get_field('header_links_link_four_url', 'options');
     $header_variabls_twelve = $ups1 = get_field('header_usps_usp_1', 'options');
     $header_variabls_thirteen = $ups2 = get_field('header_usps_usp_2', 'options');
     $header_variabls_fourtneen = $ups3 = get_field('header_usps_usp_3', 'options');    
    
    
$header_variabls = array (
     $header_variabls_one,
     $header_variabls_two,
     $header_variabls_three,
     $header_variabls_four,
     $header_variabls_five,
     $header_variabls_six,
     $header_variabls_seven,
     $header_variabls_eight,
     $header_variabls_nine,        
     $header_variabls_ten,
     $header_variabls_eleven, 
     $header_variabls_twelwe,
     $header_variabls_thirteen,
     $header_variabls_fourteen,
);
    
       
    global $post;
    global $sitepress;
    $postid = $post->ID;  
    $language = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'wpml_language', true );
    if ($language == 'en') {
        add_filter('acf/settings/current_language', function(){return 'en';});
        $header_variabls;
    } elseif ($language == 'nl') {
        add_filter('acf/settings/current_language', function(){return 'nl';});
        $header_variabls;
    } elseif ($language == 'de') {
        add_filter('acf/settings/current_language', function(){return 'de';});
        $header_variabls;
    } elseif (ICL_LANGUAGE_CODE=='en') {
        $sitepress->switch_lang( 'en', true );
        do_action( 'wpml_switch_language', "en" );
        $sitelogo = get_field('en_logo', 'options'); 
        $emailLogoLink = get_field('en_email_logo_link', 'options');
        $sitelogo = get_field('en_logo', 'options'); 
        $header_link_one = get_field('en_header_links_link_one', 'options');
        $header_link_one_url = get_field('en_header_links_link_one_url', 'options');
        $header_link_two = get_field('en_header_links_link_two', 'options');
        $header_link_two_url = get_field('en_header_links_link_two_url', 'options');
        $header_link_three = get_field('en_header_links_link_three', 'options');
        $header_link_three_url = get_field('en_header_links_link_three_url', 'options');
        $header_link_four = get_field('en_header_links_link_four', 'options');
        $header_link_four_url = get_field('en_header_links_link_four_url', 'options');
        $ups1 = get_field('en_header_usps_usp_1', 'options');
        $ups2 = get_field('en_header_usps_usp_2', 'options');
        $ups3 = get_field('en_header_usps_usp_3', 'options');   
    } elseif (ICL_LANGUAGE_CODE=='de') {
        $sitelogo = get_field('de_logo', 'options'); 
        $emailLogoLink = get_field('de_email_logo_link', 'options');
        $sitelogo = get_field('de_logo', 'options'); 
        $header_link_one = get_field('de_header_links_link_one', 'options');
        $header_link_one_url = get_field('de_header_links_link_one_url', 'options');
        $header_link_two = get_field('de_header_links_link_two', 'options');
        $header_link_two_url = get_field('de_header_links_link_two_url', 'options');
        $header_link_three = get_field('de_header_links_link_three', 'options');
        $header_link_three_url = get_field('de_header_links_link_three_url', 'options');
        $header_link_four = get_field('de_header_links_link_four', 'options');
        $header_link_four_url = get_field('de_header_links_link_four_url', 'options');
        $ups1 = get_field('de_header_usps_usp_1', 'options');
        $ups2 = get_field('de_header_usps_usp_2', 'options');
        $ups3 = get_field('de_header_usps_usp_3', 'options'); 
    } elseif (ICL_LANGUAGE_CODE=='nl') {
        $sitepress->switch_lang( 'nl', true );
        do_action( 'wpml_switch_language', "nl" );      
        $header_variabls;
    }
```

Comment: A CodeReview title must not include the kind of review that you are seeking.  The title must only describe what your script does.  You might like to add a `wordpress` tag to you question.  Please take the [tour] and [edit] your question.

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! Is `$header_variabls_fourtneen` (on the 14th line) supposed to be `$header_variabls_fourteen` (like it is on the 31st line)?

Comment: Yes! Miss-spelled. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some points to consider:

- You have a duplicate header value, site logo appears twice
- Inconsistent variable names: you are using sitelogo, emailLogoLink, and header_link_one
- It might be worth considering checking lowercase values of strings in case you get 'NL' instead of 'nl'

You can also use the header variables to store the name of the field, and then grab them later. This lets you prepend the language code to them to make it more DRY.

I used a switch statement for the check for `$ICL_LANGUAGE_CODE` as I can take advantage of fall-through to not update header fields for NL.

Note: the code below is untested, and may very well not work.

```
$headerVariables = [
    'logo',
    'email_logo_link',
    'logo',
    'header_links_link_one',
    'header_links_link_one_url',
    'header_links_link_two',
    'header_links_link_two_url',
    'header_links_link_three',
    'header_links_link_three_url',
    'header_links_link_four',
    'header_links_link_four_url',
    'header_usps_usp_1',
    'header_usps_usp_2',
    'header_usps_usp_3'];

global $post;
global $sitepress;
$postid = $post->ID;
$language = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'wpml_language', true );
if (in_array($language, ['en', 'nl', 'de'])) {
    add_filter('acf/settings/current_language', function(){return $language;});
} else {
    switch ($ICL_LANGUAGE_CODE) {
        case 'en':
        case 'de':
            foreach ($headerVariables as $key => $value) {
                $headerVariables[$key] = $ICL_LANGUAGE_CODE . '_' . $value;
            }
        case 'nl':
            $sitepress->switch_lang( $ICL_LANGUAGE_CODE, true );
            do_action( 'wpml_switch_language', $ICL_LANGUAGE_CODE);
    }
}

// Get all header variables
foreach ($headerVariables as $key => $value) {
    $headerVariables[$key] = get_field($value, 'options');
}

// set variables in case we need them later
$sitelogo = $headerVariables[0];
$emailLogoLink = $headerVariables[1];
$sitelogo = $headerVariables[2];
$header_link_one = $headerVariables[3];
$header_link_one_url = $headerVariables[4];
$header_link_two = $headerVariables[5];
$header_link_two_url = $headerVariables[6];
$header_link_three = $headerVariables[7];
$header_link_three_url = $headerVariables[8];
$header_link_four = $headerVariables[9];
$header_link_four_url = $headerVariables[10];
$ups1 = $headerVariables[11];
$ups2 = $headerVariables[12];
$ups3 = $headerVariables[13];
```

Comment: Are you sure about that `switch()` block? I don't see any `break`s. I think I'd use a `default` case instead of having to maintain an `in_array()` function and a `switch()` block.

Comment: @mickmackusa taken from the [PHP manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.switch.php): `If you don't write a break statement at the end of a case's statement list, PHP will go on executing the statements of the following case.`

Comment: So you mean that `en` and `de` should also fall through to `nl`?  If so, then I don't see any need to write the two lines of code under `nl` -- just write them after the `switch` block.

Comment: As far as what I'd use there. I'm not 100% sure I'd use what I put either. But either way multiple if or switch statements are needed as you need to check multiple variables. I think it's a matter of preference, and if working with a team would try to align my code with existing code.

Comment: @mickmackusa Yeah, they should also fall through to `nl` but `nl` language should not run the code for `en` and `de`. So we have the `nl` in there to show where the `nl` code should start from.

Comment: I guess what I mean to say is if this is what you mean https://3v4l.org/qiDbY, then `case 'nl':` doesn't need to be in the `switch` at all.  I just feel like it is trying to trick my eyes with multiple cases and no breaks.

Comment: @mickmackusa the main issue with that is that what's in the `nl` section would then be executed for all languages. But based on the code given, the code should only execute for `en`, `de`, and `nl`. So I do understand your aversion to the switch with no breaks, a number of people don't like it, and it could be broken into multiple if statements instead with slightly more code needed. See https://3v4l.org/bliTB for an example.

Answer (score 3):

Although I am pretty new to PHP/WordPress myself, one item I saw right away to make your code prettier is spacing.

From the [WordPress PHP Coding Standards section on indentation](https://developer.wordpress.org/coding-standards/wordpress-coding-standards/php/#indentation)

> Your indentation should always reflect logical structure. Use **real tabs** and **not spaces**, as this allows the most flexibility across clients.
>
> Exception: if you have a block of code that would be more readable if things are aligned, use spaces:
>
> ```
> [tab]$foo   = 'somevalue';
> [tab]$foo2  = 'somevalue2';
> [tab]$foo34 = 'somevalue3';
> [tab]$foo5  = 'somevalue4';
> ```

Also for prettiness you should have a lot more spaces:
Always put spaces after commas, and on both sides of logical, comparison, string and assignment operators. (from that same page from WordPress)

Another quick win is 'options' is repeated throughout the page. You can set a variable at the top to repeat this.

I also removed the double variable as it didn't seem necessary but I may not know something there so have caution. It just didn't seem necessary.

Lastly, you spelled out numbers instead of writing them, this was a lot of extra characters you could have just used numbers in.

```
<?php

$o = 'options';

$sitelogo               = get_field( 'logo', $o ); 
$emailLogoLink          = get_field( 'email_logo_link', $o );
$sitelogo               = get_field( 'logo', $o ); 
$header_link_1          = get_field( 'header_links_link_1', $o );
$header_link_1_url      = get_field( 'header_links_link_1_url', $o );
$header_link_2          = get_field( 'header_links_link_2', $o );
$header_link_2_url      = get_field( 'header_links_link_2_url', $o );
$header_link_3          = get_field( 'header_links_link_3', $o );
$header_link_3_url      = get_field( 'header_links_link_3_url', $o );
$header_link_4          = get_field( 'header_links_link_4', $o );
$header_link_4_url      = get_field( 'header_links_link_4_url', $o );
$ups1                   = get_field( 'header_usps_usp_1', $o );
$ups2                   = get_field( 'header_usps_usp_2', $o );
$ups3                   = get_field( 'header_usps_usp_3', $o );    
    
    
$header_variabls = array (
    $sitelogo,             
    $emailLogoLink,        
    $sitelogo,             
    $header_link_1,      
    $header_link_1_url,  
    $header_link_2,      
    $header_link_2_url,  
    $header_link_3,    
    $header_link_3_url,
    $header_link_4,     
    $header_link_4_url, 
    $ups1,                 
    $ups2,                 
    $ups3,                 
);
    
       
    global $post;
    global $sitepress;
    $postid     = $post->ID;  
    $language   = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'wpml_language', true );
    if ( $language == 'en' ) {
        add_filter( 'acf/settings/current_language', function(){ return 'en'; } );
        $header_variabls;
    } elseif ( $language == 'nl' ) {
        add_filter( 'acf/settings/current_language', function(){ return 'nl'; } );
        $header_variabls;
    } elseif ( $language == 'de' ) {
        add_filter( 'acf/settings/current_language', function(){ return 'de'; } );
        $header_variabls;
    } elseif ( ICL_LANGUAGE_CODE=='en' ) {
        $sitepress->switch_lang( 'en', true );
        do_action( 'wpml_switch_language', "en" );
        $sitelogo               = get_field('en_logo', $o); 
        $emailLogoLink          = get_field('en_email_logo_link', $o);
        $sitelogo               = get_field('en_logo', $o); 
        $header_link_1          = get_field('en_header_links_link_1', $o);
        $header_link_1_url      = get_field('en_header_links_link_1_url', $o);
        $header_link_2          = get_field('en_header_links_link_2', $o);
        $header_link_2_url      = get_field('en_header_links_link_2_url', $o);
        $header_link_3          = get_field('en_header_links_link_3', $o);
        $header_link_3_url      = get_field('en_header_links_link_3_url', $o);
        $header_link_4          = get_field('en_header_links_link_4', $o);
        $header_link_4_url      = get_field('en_header_links_link_4_url', $o);
        $ups1                   = get_field('en_header_usps_usp_1', $o);
        $ups2                   = get_field('en_header_usps_usp_2', $o);
        $ups3                   = get_field('en_header_usps_usp_3', $o);   
    } elseif ( ICL_LANGUAGE_CODE=='de' ) {
        $sitelogo               = get_field('de_logo', $o); 
        $emailLogoLink          = get_field('de_email_logo_link', $o);
        $sitelogo               = get_field('de_logo', $o);
        $header_link_1          = get_field('de_header_links_link_1', $o);
        $header_link_1_url      = get_field('de_header_links_link_1_url', $o);
        $header_link_2          = get_field('de_header_links_link_2', $o);
        $header_link_2_url      = get_field('de_header_links_link_2_url', $o);
        $header_link_3          = get_field('de_header_links_link_3', $o);
        $header_link_3_url      = get_field('de_header_links_link_3_url', $o);
        $header_link_4          = get_field('de_header_links_link_4', $o);
        $header_link_4_url      = get_field('de_header_links_link_4_url', $o);
        $ups1                   = get_field('de_header_usps_usp_1', $o);
        $ups2                   = get_field('de_header_usps_usp_2', $o);
        $ups3                   = get_field('de_header_usps_usp_3', $o); 
    } elseif ( ICL_LANGUAGE_CODE=='nl' ) {
        $sitepress->switch_lang( 'nl', true );
        do_action( 'wpml_switch_language', "nl" );      
        $header_variabls;
    }

    ?>
```

Comment: I'd highly suggest using [PSR](https://www.php-fig.org/psr/) instead of WP's code standards. At the end of the day you are writing code in PHP regardless of what framework or alike you are using. You never know, a piece of code you used in a WP project, you might use it somewhere else not to mention actually following PHP / Core language standards should always be preferred.